# Javascript Array.find method sometimes returns item, sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, find

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const list = [["GET", /github/g]];
```

It's an array with a sub array, index 0 having a string, index 1 having a regular expression.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function checkList() {
    return list.find(i => i[0] === "GET" && i[1].test("github.com"));
}
```

Which I would expect to return the list it finds every time, but that's not the case, it flips back and forth from returning the list and returning `undefined`.

Here's an example:

```js
let i = 1;
const list = [["GET", /github/g]];
while (i <=10) {
    console.log(list.find(i => i[0] === "GET" && i[1].test("github.com")))
    i++
}
```

In this example I just loop through it and log the results to show that it returns the list and `undefined` every other time. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the RegExp in `i[1]` is actually stateful. Your code calls `i[1].test(...)` on odd iterations, matching against `"github"` in `"github.com"`, and advancing `lastIndex`. Then, on the next even iteration, the next call to `test` fails to find another match, reaching the end of the string. After that, the RegExp restarts the search from the beginning of the string.

If you would just like to check whether the pattern is found at least once, you could simply remove the `/g` flag at the end.

From MDN docs:

> As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: As an another solution, he might need to use `string.match(regex)` instead.

Comment: True, although, I don't immediately see a need for a global match in this case anyway. I'd lean more towards not using features that aren't necessary.

Comment: I'm building a library that other people are going to use, so I can't just remove the /g because that might be something that someone wants to use in a url pattern. However, @QuyetNguyen 's solution of changing it to be `match` appeared to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @QuyetNguyen, you should probably post it as an answer